# How to add additional text at top of moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

An application requires me to upload my resume and to include the department to which I am applying at the top of the document. May I know how I can do so with the moderncv ? I tried the solution posted at [Place framed text at top of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82900/place-framed-text-at-top-of-page) but not for resume type documents and it failed. The code I have below gave me this. I wasnt able to put the text at the top of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.6cm}
\recomputelengths

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize }

% personal datas
\firstname{Haziq}
\familyname{Razali}
\address{Bukit Batok West Ave 6}{Block 189 \#15-27}
\mobile{(+65)9172-2319}              
%\email{ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com} 
\extrainfo{ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com\\
}
\photo[84pt]{Haziq.jpg}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=false,
urlbordercolor=red,
pdfborder = {0 0 1}
}
}

\nopagenumbers{} % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rm={lining,proportional},sf={lining,proportional},tt={lining,tabular,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\global\let\bfseries\sbweight

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {some text};
\node[draw,align=left] at (3,0) {some text\\ spanning three lines\\ with manual line breaks};
\node[draw,text width=4cm] at (2,-2) {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}

%Section
\section{Education}

\cventry{2013 -- 2016}{Nanyang Technological University}{}{}{}{\normalsize{B.Eng. Electrical and Electronics Engineering, 1st Class Honours} \newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Experience} 
%
\cventry{Aug 2016 -- Aug 2017}{%\href{http://www.ipal.cnrs.fr/}
{Image \& Pervasive Access Lab - National University of Singapore}}{\textnormal{Research Engineer}}{\textit{Object Detection \& Recognition in RGBD images} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Proposed and implemented an object proposal pipeline for 3D point clouds that exploits intervoxel statistics from training data \vspace{5mm}
\item Currently experimenting with various modifications to the Fast-RCNN architecture to include said statistics and features that represent prior knowledge. Planning for submission to ICIP
\vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}} 

\cventry{May 2016 -- Jul 2016}{%\href{http://www.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/department/vc/index.html}
{Institute for Infocomm Research}}{\textnormal{Intern}}{\textit{Object Detection \& Recognition for Mobility Safety Applications} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a survey of Deep Learning methods and developed an end-to-end CNN for pedestrian detection in RGB-Thermal images \vspace{5mm} 
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Aug 2015 -- Apr 2016}{%\href{http://adsc.illinois.edu/}
{Advanced Digital Sciences Centre}}{\textnormal{Junior Research Assistant}}{\textit{Real Time Automated Analysis of Soccer Videos}\vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Designed algorithms that enhanced the ball tracker by utilizing the rules and \textit{a-priori} knowledge of soccer and implemented height estimation techniques based on the epipolar geometry of stereo vision \vspace{5mm}
\item Designed an algorithm for unsupervised learning of player-team based on k-means clustering and improved the kalman-filtering based player tracker with an occlusion handler that employed an adaptive template  \vspace{5mm}
\item Worked on camera calibration and homography for the mapping of objects onto a common coordinate system for object fusion and analysis in world coordinates \vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Jan 2015 -- May 2015}{Nanyang Technological University}{}{\textit{Face Recognition - Undergraduate Research Opportunities Program} \vspace{2mm}}{}{ 
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a detailed survey of existing techniques on 2D Face Recognition and implemented PCA and LDA on Matlab for performance evaluation \vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                       AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cventry{2014  -- 2016}{\mdseries{Yayasan Mendaki - Institution of Engineers (Singapore) Scholarship}}{}{}{}{\footnotesize{The scholarship is awarded to \normalsize{\textbf{one Malay student}} per year across all engineering disciplines by nomination from NUS/NTU/SIT/SUTD\newline{}}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize\color{black}(Proficient, \color{gray}Basic)}
\cvitem{Languages}{C++, Matlab, \color{gray} Python}
\cvitem{Libraries}{OpenCV, Point Cloud Library, OpenMP, MatConvNet, \color{gray} Caffe\newline{}}
%\cvitem{Others}{LaTeX\newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                      SERVICE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{References}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{}

\cventry{}{Dr. Nizar Ouarti}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Associate Professor}\newline Image and Pervasive Access Lab / Université Pierre et Marie Curie \newline nizar.ouarti@ipal.cnrs.fr \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Lu Shijian}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Scientist II / Adjunct Assistant Professor}\newline Institute for Infocomm Research / Nanyang Technological University \newline slu@i2r.a-star.edu.sg \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Stefan Winkler}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Principal Research Scientist}\newline Advanced Digital Sciences Center / U. of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign \newline Stefan.Winkler@adsc.com.sg \newline}

\closesection{}                   % needed to renewcommands

\end{document}
```

Comment: please show the code you already tried an a picture of what you would like to have.

Comment: Place the `tikzpicture` environment before `\maketitle`

Comment: Wow that was simple ! Do you know how I could set a maximum width for the text box such that it enters a new line if it reaches the default page width ? It seems like // does not work in this case

Comment: Ok it looks like the solution here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24372/how-to-add-newline-within-node-using-tikz is perfect

Answer (score 1):

`\maketitle` prints the title there and then, in order to place images above the title, simply place the relevant TeX code before `\maketitle` i.e.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {some text};
\node[draw,align=left] at (3,0) {some text\\ spanning three lines\\ with manual line breaks};
\node[draw,text width=4cm] at (2,-2) {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}

\maketitle
```

This will then place the contents of the `tikzpicture` environment at the top of the page.

[image]